# Trouble With Bootstrap Modal, IE7, and PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, modal-dialog

Having some trouble building a "dashboard" web tool for the company I work for.  The dashboard uses a DataTable to display customer information, pulling the data from a MySQL database using a PHP `while` loop.

I have a button on each row of the table:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="#job_info_" . $row['id'] . ""><i class="icon-question-sign icon-white"></i></a>
```

This calls for the unique Modal box (Example:  #job_info_42)

The code for the Modal Box is:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="job_info_" . $row['id'] . "">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3>Project Details For ".$row['customer']."</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<span><strong>Current Status:</strong> ".$status. $quote_notify ."</span> <br><br>

".$row['details']."

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div>"
```

I have tested this code using IE10, Chrome, Safari, and on my Smartphone.
**It works great, except in IE9 (havent tested older ie versions).**
The code fails to call the modal box (it doesn't appear). Unfortunately IE9 is the official browser in my company.

I'll be happy to post any additional code at request.

Comment: In IE9 open the Developer Tools window using F12. I'm not on a Windows machine right now but there should be a 'script' or 'console' tab - take a look there it is likely to give some clues.

Comment: Hi DrBeza, thank you for your response. I did as you suggested and there was only a single error, however it is unrelated. There was an error in a JS file controlling a UI element in the dashboard (a slider). The problem still persists.

Comment: Can you recreate this problem in a jsfiddle or perhaps provide a link to your dev site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for their help with this problem.

While I was building a sample of my error on jsfiddle, I noticed I had a few old scripts on my site from ideas I scratched.  When I removed those unused (but still linked) js files, my problem went away.  There must have been some conflict happening in the back that wasn't being noticed.

The files I removed were:

- jquery.masonry.min.js
- jquery.imagesloaded.js
- jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js
- jquery.raty.min.js
- jquery.elfinder.min.js

Once again, thank you all.